# Dont Match escaped characters in Regex

Tags: java, regex

I have some string which in a sunny day scenario looks like

```
'abcd' => 'efgh'
```

Where i want to get `abcd` and `efgh` in capture groups like

```
"'([^']*)'\s*=>\s*'([^']*)'"
```

My Problem now is, that => or \\' might occur within the capture sequences. I already tried

```
"'([^']|[\\\\^]*)'\s*=>\s*'([^']|[\\\\']*)'"
```

But this did not get me to the desired result.
How do i filter out those to values?

Comment: Looks like the safest will be `"'([^\\\\']*(?:\\\\.[^\\\\']*)*)'\\s*=>\\s*'([^\\\\']*(?:\\\\.[^\\\\']*)*)'"`

Comment: In a quick test with '\\'=>asdws' => '\\'ljsad=>asd' your Expression does not match for me

Comment: Of course, if your string can contain those values, there is no point in limiting the match to strings that do *not* contain it. What happens if you just use .* instead of `[^']`?

Comment: If i use .* he will match the last ' in the text. 
Which means he will match everything in between the first and the last ' of the demo line

Comment: The values of the string are only limited to be ASCII, so every sequence might occur in this, except ' has to be escaped

Comment: @chenino: Was the second comment from above addressed to me? Please do not forget to add `@`+`username` to let us know of your feedback.  See [**this Java demo**](http://ideone.com/RIXNAQ) showing the regex works *perfectly*.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i tested your demo and it works as you said. If you post this as an aswer i will mark it correct.

Comment: Anyhow @slartidan convinced me to use a Parser library

Comment: In that case, accept that answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew , ok. But your help is very much appreciated anyhow!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regular expressions are not the right choice, when it comes to **parsing** text.

Parsing for example includes the functionality of *counting* backslashes, quotes, etc.

Use a parser library (like *ANTLR*), or live with a semi-robust regular expression solution.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get those strings before and after "=>" you can use this:

```
String s = "'ab'cd' => 'e\\fg\\'h'";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("'(.+)'\\s\\=>\\s'(.+)'");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

if (m.matches()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
}
```

You will get "ab'cd" and "e\fg\'h" in this concrete case.

Comment: This does not work, if a => occurs within the capture Group, see my sample string in the second comment

Comment: it works even when String s = "'\\\\'=>asdws' => '\\\\'ljsad=>asd'"; in that case you get "\\'=>asdws" and "\\'ljsad=>asd".

Comment: I entered your Code in @WiktorStribiżew template, but it does not match. Sorry